# Get value from Javascript to HTML in Laravel pdf

Tags: html, laravel

when i want to export my form to pdf i want to show birthday as age

**Here is my Laravel Html:**

```html
<div id="Profil" style="text-align: left;" >
    <p><img class="icone" src="img/CIN.png "> <b>{{$form_data[$table_name]['cin']}}</b><br></p>
    <p  id="age"><img class="icone" src="img/age.png "> <b>{{$form_data[$table_name]['birthday']}}</b><br></p>
    <p><img class="icone" src="img/mail.png " ><b> {{$form_data[$table_name]['email']}}</b><br></p>
    
    <p><img class="icone" src="img/phone.png " ><b>{{$form_data[$table_name]['phone']}}</b><br></p>  
    <p><img class="icone" src="img/home.png " ><b>{{$form_data[$table_name]['address']}}</b><br></p>        
</div>
```

[here is my form export to pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkl1z.png)

[here is my pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLN6m.png)

[and i want show it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdlMX.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please read guidelines for asking a good question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you tagged it as Laravel so I'll assume that you have Carbon package installed.
In that case, it's pretty straightforward.

```
Carbon::createFromDate(1997, 01, 02)->age;
```

in your particular case something like this should work:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($form_data[$table_name]['birthday'])->age . ' ans' }}
```